# Mysql cannot handle connection anymore after migrating to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

We recently migrated project to PDO and after that mysql/phpfpm is not able to handle the request anymore.
Few process in waiting state and have to restart php-fpm frequently to restore mysql state.

Servers are high configuration so no issue with memory. Cannot figure out why mysql connections are not getting cleared and are remained in waiting state. Looked at max connection, connection waiting time too and all are well enough.

Can anyone help to figure out the issue?

Comment: Without any code for context, best we can do is say "Sorry, that sounds crappy."

Comment: Are you maybe using persistent connections?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz, no we are not using persistent connection.